# Menu Items always appears in the overflow menu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

This is my main.xml in menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:themomotrail="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_login"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Login"
    themomotrail:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

</menu>
```

This is my theme.xml

```
<!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

    <!-- <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item> -->


    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/ActionBarTabBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabTextStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/action_bar</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/action_bar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBarTabs" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@color/action_bar</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="ActionBarTabBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>

    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="background">@drawable/tab_bar_background</item>
</style>

<style name="TabTextStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">5dip</item>
</style>
```

I'm using this custom theme for the application. The problem here is, the menu item always appears in the overflow menu instead of appearing in the actionbar. What am I doing wrong ? Thanks

Comment: if there is not enough roon in the actionbar items appear in the overflow menu. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the menu xml, the `themomotrail` namespace is wrong

You have:

```
xmlns:themomotrail="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

It should be:

```
xmlns:themomotrail="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```